Example for the Global Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for ODEs
Title: Examples for Different Cases of the Global Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for ODEs
Hello,
I have a question regarding the Global Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for ordinary differential equations (ODEs) for Lipschitz continuous functions.
$f \in L(J \times D,E)$. Then for every $(t_0, x_0) \in J\times D$ there exists a unique nonextendible solution $u(\cdot, t_0, x_0) \colon J(t_0, x_0) \to D$ of the IVP.
I am looking for examples for the following case 3:

Case 1: The solution u is defined on the entire interval  J   $ f: J \times D \to E \ , u' = f $ (means $t^+=sup$ J).
Case 2: The solution u tends to infinity and is therefore not defined on the entire interval ( J ).
Case 3: The solution u approaches the boundary of  D , that is, $\lim_{t \to t^+} dist(u(t), \partial D) = 0$.

I have examples for Cases 1 and 2, but I am struggling to find an example for Case 3.

But this function isn't Lipschitz continuous on (−1,1) and u=sin(t) then $t^+=sup J$ right?

i am still confused: first f(t,u(t)) is not Lipschitz continuous on (-1,1) and you mean u(t)=1 for $t\geq\pi/2$ right? How do you get the interval for t?

Then ignore my example.
